# LINQ: Remove Element from XML based on attribute value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

How can I remove any element in xml based on matched attribute value?

Here is my XML :

```
<Projects>
    <Project serverUrl="tcp://xyz1:xxx/sdfsdf.rem" projectName="project1" />
    <Project serverUrl="tcp://xyz2:xxx/sdfsdf.rem" projectName="project2" />
    <Project serverUrl="tcp://xyz3:xxx/sdfsdf.rem" projectName="project3" />
    <Project serverUrl="tcp://xyz4:xxx/sdfsdf.rem" projectName="project4" />
    <Project serverUrl="tcp://xyz5:xxx/sdfsdf.rem" projectName="project5" />
    <Project serverUrl="tcp://xyz6:xxx/sdfsdf.rem" projectName="project6" />
   </Projects>
```

I am using the following LINQ query:

```
var remove = from elemet in xdoc.Elements("Projects").Elements("Project")
                                 where elemet.Attribute("projectName").Value == "project1"
                                 select elemet.Parent.Remove();
```

I am getting compile time error on select as :

> The type of expression in select
>   clause is Incorrect

EDIT ANSWER:
this one works for me. Thanks All

```
var xElement = (from elemet in xdoc.Elements("Projects").Elements("Project")
                            where elemet.Attribute("projectName").Value == foundProject
                            select elemet);
            xElement.Remove();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet:

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElement("Projects/Project[@projectName = 'project1']").Remove();
```

Answer (score 10):

`Remove` is a (void) method call, not a function that can return a value. You probably want something like this:

```
var elementsToRemove = from elemet in xdoc.Elements("Projects").Elements("Project")
                       where elemet.Attribute("projectName").Value == "project1"
                       select elemet;

foreach (var e in elementsToRemove)
    e.Remove();
```

LINQ is a *query* language, it's (mainly) used to *return* something. Performing *actions* on these elements is usually a separate step.

Answer (score 7):

You could use

```
xdoc.Elements("Projects").Elements("Project").Where(
                    elemet => elemet.Attribute("projectName").Value == "project1")
.ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());
```

or

```
(from elemet in xdoc.Elements("Projects").Elements("Project")
                          where elemet.Attribute("projectName").Value == "project1"
                          select elemet).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Remove()` is a method you call on an XNode. Your query is trying to *select* the method which doesn't make any sense.

What you actually want to do is select the item you wish to remove, then call the Remove() method on the selected item. You can find an example here:
[XNode.Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx)