# How to remove an xml element from file?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0

In an XML file such as :

```
<Snippets>
 <Snippet name="abc">
   <SnippetCode>
   code goes here
   </SnippetCode>
 </Snippet>

 <Snippet name="def">
   <SnippetCode>
   code goes here
   </SnippetCode>
 </Snippet>
</Snippets>
```

How can I remove an element when only its attribute name (like `abc` or `def`) is given?

Comment: you dont need winforms tag. Plausible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004481/linq-remove-element-fron-xml-based-on-attribute-value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
string xmlInput = @"<Snippets>
 <Snippet name=""abc"">
   <SnippetCode>
   code goes here
   </SnippetCode>
 </Snippet>

 <Snippet name=""def"">
   <SnippetCode>
   code goes here
   </SnippetCode>
 </Snippet>
</Snippets>";

// create the XML, load the contents
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlInput);

// find a node - here the one with name='abc'
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Snippets/Snippet[@name='abc']");

// if found....
if (node != null)
{
   // get its parent node
   XmlNode parent = node.ParentNode;

   // remove the child node
   parent.RemoveChild(node);

   // verify the new XML structure
   string newXML = doc.OuterXml;

   // save to file or whatever....
   doc.Save(@"C:\temp\new.xml");
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. My code is actually mostly the same, but I had difficulty getting the name attribute. Thanks.

Comment: I hate it when someone beats me to the punch :)  Pretty much the code I had written.

Comment: @LeslieHanks: happens to me, too - all the time :-)

Comment: @marc_s How this particular use of @ inside the [ ] is called? Thank you

Comment: @franz1: referencing an XML **attribute** (not an element)

Comment: @marc_s is the "@" a particular operator in C#? I couldn't find any documentation about... Thank you

Comment: @franz1: no, it's part of the **XPath** standard: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp - the `XmlDocument` uses XPath expressions to select certain nodes (or attributes) from a XML document

Comment: @marc_s In your opinion can I combine the @ with disjunction inside a single statement? I want to find a node where the x attribute OR the y attribute OR both are equal to the specified value. So far I declared two variables to store two different nodes for each attribute, and used disjunction inside a conditional expression into an if statement: I wonder if there was any better way to put that by using the mentioned XPath, so I can minimize code...

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use LINQ to XML, that makes it very easy indeed:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var query = doc.Descendants("Snippet")
               .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "def");

//  Using extension method
query.Remove();
```

(The question is tagged .NET 2.0, but in 2022 it seems reasonable to assume most users can use LINQ to XML...)

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("Snippet")
    let attr = node.Attribute("name")
    where attr != null && attr.Value == "abc"
    select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

.Net 2.0

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("input.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Snippet[@name='abc']");
```

Now you have the nodes whose attribute name='abc', you can now loop through it and delete

Comment: you should add Tag for .net 2.0

Comment: I initially wrote this code, but I'm now using NET 2. and I'm having trouble degrading it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  XElement xEmp = XElement.Load(@"C://Users//Khulu//Documents//Visual Studio 2012//Projects//AMD//Schedule//ToDo.xml");
            //
            xEmp.Add(
                     new XElement("ToDo",
                      new XElement("Item", item),
                       new XElement("date", date),
                        new XElement("time", time),
                        new XElement("due", due),
                        new XElement("description", description))
            );
            xEmp.Save(@"C://Users//Khulu//Documents//Visual Studio 2012//Projects//AMD//Schedule//ToDo.xml");`  XElement xEmp = XElement.Load(@"C://Users//Khulu//Documents//Visual Studio 2012//Projects//AMD//Schedule//ToDo.xml");
            //
            xEmp.Add(
                     new XElement("ToDo",
                      new XElement("Item", item),
                       new XElement("date", date),
                        new XElement("time", time),
                        new XElement("due", due),
                        new XElement("description", description))
            );
            xEmp.Save(@"C://Users//Khulu//Documents//Visual Studio 2012//Projects//AMD//Schedule//ToDo.xml");`
```