# Remove an XML element based on child index

Tags: c#, xml

I found this question:
[How to remove an xml element from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382834/how-to-remove-an-xml-element-from-file)
Which seems to work fine if you know some info within the element you want to delete.
But I have a OnItemDeleting function in ASP.NET where I only have (I think) the Selected Index of the item in a ListView.

In my C# file I have defined two alternatives (A and B) as you can see, it looks like this:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IN ON ITEM DELETING.");
        ListView1.SelectedIndex = e.ItemIndex;

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(path);

        XmlNodeList nodes = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("EmployeeInformation");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == ListView1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                nodes[i].RemoveChild(nodes[i]); // Alt. A
                xmldoc.RemoveChild(nodes[i]); // Alt. B
                break;
            }
        }
        xmldoc.Save(path);
        BindDatalist();
```

If I try something like A, I dont know how to replace the nodes in the XmlDocument with the nodes in the XmlNodeList, and if I do like B it just doesn't work and also its weird.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<EmployeeInformation>
  <Details>
    <Name>Goofy</Name>
    <Emp_id>Goooof</Emp_id>
    <Qualification>BBA</Qualification>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <Name>Donald</Name>
    <Emp_id>Duck</Emp_id>
    <Qualification>MTech</Qualification>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <Name>Donald</Name>
    <Emp_id>Trump</Emp_id>
    <Qualification>MCA</Qualification>
  </Details>
</EmployeeInformation>
```

So lets say I want to remove the Donald Trump item by clicking a button next to it. The selectedIndex would be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case looping XmlNodeList not required.

try this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);

            if (ListView1.SelectedIndex < doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count)
            {
                doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[ListView1.SelectedIndex]);
                doc.Save(path);
            }
```

Comment: thank you alot for that answer. This works perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Specifying that the node to be deleted from the XlmNodeList is a parent node solved the problem:

```
ListView1.SelectedIndex = e.ItemIndex;

XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(path);

XmlNodeList nodes = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Details");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == e.ItemIndex)
    {

        nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
        break;
    }
}
xmldoc.Save(path);
BindDatalist();
```

Comment: Even though this worked as I suggested, the solution provided by @Azar Shaikh was perfect.