# Deleting elements from xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm mapping into a gridView asp, the items of the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" version="1.0" xml:lang="es-MX" mode="voice" tag-format="semantics/1.0" root="grmVoz">
  <rule id="grmVoz" scope="public">
    <ruleref uri="#rule1" />
    <tag>out.cxtag=rules.rule1;out.rule1=rules.rule1;</tag>
  </rule>
  <rule id="rule1">
    <tag>out='';</tag>
    <one-of>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto<tag>out+="out1"</tag></item>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto2<tag>out+="out2"</tag></item>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto3<tag>out+="out3"</tag></item>
      <item weight="1.0">Ivan Alberto4<tag>out+="out4"</tag></item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>
</grammar>
```

I trying to delete a specific item, when click in the delete button of the gridView.

this is my code :

```
protected void gvGrammars_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvGrammars.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string valor = row.Cells[0].Text;
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("voiceGrammar.grxml"));
     xdoc.Descendants("grammar").Elements("rule")
        .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "rule1").Elements("one-of").Elements("item").Where(y=> (string)y.Value == valor)
        .Remove();
xdoc.Save(Server.MapPath("voiceGrammar.grxml"));
    }
```

but nothing happend.

I used instead of Desendant :

```
xdoc.Elements("grammar")
```

please can you check if i missed something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382834/how-to-remove-an-xml-element-from-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changes below.  When removing items from a list you need to remove from end of list to beginning so you do not skip items.  Fir example if you have 4,5,6 and remove 5.  6 becomes 5 and you end up skipping 6.  You were also missing the namespace.

```
protected void gvGrammars_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvGrammars.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string valor = row.Cells[0].Text;
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("voiceGrammar.grxml"));
    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
    List<XElement> itemToDelete = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "rule")
        .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "rule1")
        .Select(y => y.Descendants(ns + "item")
        .Where(z => z.FirstNode.ToString() == valor))
        .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

    for (int i = itemToDelete.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        itemToDelete[i].Remove();
    }
    xdoc.Save(Server.MapPath("voiceGrammar.grxml"));
}
```

Comment: itemsToDelete is  returning nothing, the count is 0. What is wrong in the linq Query ?

Comment: Thanks, for the answer it working now, please add to your answer that i forgot to put the nameSpaces , and to obtain the value in the las where i was taking the wrong value.