# Remove element from XML based on attribute value?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I was trying to remove a descendant element from an XElement *(using .Remove())* and I seem to get a null object reference, and I'm not sure why.

Having looked at the previous question with this title *([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004481/))*, I found a way to remove it, but I still don't see why the way I tried 1st didn't work.

Can someone enlighten me ?

```
  String xml = "<things>"
             + "<type t='a'>"
             + "<thing id='100'/>"
             + "<thing id='200'/>"
             + "<thing id='300'/>"
             + "</type>"
             + "</things>";

  XElement bob = XElement.Parse(xml);

  // this doesn't work...
  var qry = from element in bob.Descendants()
            where element.Attribute("id").Value == "200"
            select element;
  if (qry.Count() > 0)
     qry.First().Remove();

  // ...but this does
  bob.XPathSelectElement("//thing[@id = '200']").Remove();
```

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the collection you are iterating contains some element that don't have the `id` attribute. For them, `element.Attribute("id")` is `null`, and so trying to access the `Value` property throws a `NullReferenceException`.

One way to solve this is to use [a cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339184.aspx) instead of `Value`:

```
var qry = from element in bob.Descendants()
          where (string)element.Attribute("id") == "200"
          select element;
```

If an element doesn't have the `id` attribute, the cast will returns `null`, which works fine here.

And if you're doing a cast, you can just as well cast to an `int?`, if you want.

Comment: Thanks svick, I see what the issue is now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
  var qry = bob.Descendants()
               .Where(el => el .Attribute("id") != null)
               .Where(el => el .Attribute("id").Value = "200")

  if (qry.Count() > 0)
     qry.First().Remove();
```

You need to test for the presence of the `id` attribute before getting its value.

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice re. checking attributes - I see why its relevant in the light of svick's answer.

Comment: @BlackLight oh well, it was worth a try!

Comment: Well, no offense but it's been over three years and I'm really surprised how no body saw any errors in this code. There are 3 very noticeable mistakes. `el .Attribute` has white space both times and `Attribute("id").Value = "200"` should have been `Attribute("id").Value == "200"` instead. Notice the double = sign.